# Avoiding reloading entities many times with EF Core and Mediatr

Tags: performance, enterprise-architecture, cqrs, efcore

We have a largeish .NET Core project which uses Mediatr and EF Core. Many of the queries look something like:

```
public class GetSomeInformation : IRequest<string>
{
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }
}
```

and we load the entities with `AsNoTracking` to avoid issues with attaching duplicate entities if we need to update them, so the handler will typically look something like:

```
public class GetSomeInformationHandler : IRequestHandler<GetSomeInformation, string>
{
    public async Task<string> Handle(GetSomeInformation  query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var document = Context.Documents
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(x => x.Id == query.DocumentId)
            .Include(x => x.Something)
            .Include(x => x.SomethingElse)
            .Include(x => x.MoreThings)
            .SingleAsync(cancellationToken);
        
        ...
    }
}
```

Although this allows these handlers to behave like highly decoupled microservices, we find that we sometimes end up loading the same entity 5-6 times within some API calls, by calling several mediator queries.

We could solve this by passing the actual entity inside all queries, like:

```
public class GetSomeInformation : IRequest<string>
{
    public Document Document { get; set; }
}
```

Which will work fine, but feels a bit "unclean". I guess technically the messages should be something easily serializable? In practice, it will work in our project of course, we just have in-process CQRS with Mediatr.

Is there a better way to avoid reloading?

Comment: Would caching at the HTTP layer be a better solution? Is this really causing a problem?

Comment: Why do you consider the alternate approach to be unclean?

Comment: @GregBurghardt: since many users work on the same entities at once, and they are also linked in certain ways so that changing one entity can affect the others, we cannot really cache the end results.

Comment: @Flater: well that's also a good point, not sure tbh :) One concern is that the entities have navigational properties which are needed only by some queries. If you just pass the entity Id, then the query handler just includes the properties it needs. With this change, if a certain query needs some included property, it is the caller's responsibility to fully load the entity and all properties. But going this route would probably mean we'd just include load all properties and forget about it.

Comment: I assume your db context has been registered as a transient dependency? Any particular reason why you didn't register it as scoped?

Comment: @Flater: it's scoped, but does it make a difference? Each time you do `Context.Documents.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.Id == id).Single()`, EF Core will create a new query, right?

Comment: @Lou Few things to mention: (1) Yes, but I needed the info to understand the better solution for your specific case (2) `Where` is not the recommended approach on finding an element by its PK value. `Find` is (3) It is unclear to me why you _must_ use `AsNoTracking`, especially since you want the caching part of the tracking behavior. I suspect this is an XY problem that stems from you not knowing how to attach a different entity when another (of the same PK) is already being tracked; thus leading you to avoid the tracking instead of attaching it the right way. Is this suspicion correct?

Comment: @Flater: yes you nailed the main issue perfectly :) It's a largish legacy project where `AsNoTracking` is literally added to the "service" query method, enabling it for all queries. Which also means that, whenever we update anything, EF core updates all properties in the entity, so it's crappy from a performance standpoint also. So anyway, thanks for the tips, I will probably just pass the instance to the mediator command and solve the issue this way.